# Como mover um gráfico (Highcharts) usando as setas do teclado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Como faço para mover um gráfico, usando Highcharts?

Em vez de mover com o mouse para a direita e para a esquerda, eu gostaria de usar as teclas direcionais (seta para direita, para esquerda, para cima, e para baixo).

http://goo.gl/oJ71Dx

Este exemplo usa o mouse para mover; eu preciso fazer com as teclas. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é muito difícil. O Highcharts tem um objeto muito rico que você pode manipular. Eu atualizei seu fiddle com uma [solução para mover para os lados com o teclado](http://jsfiddle.net/da63rp7u/2/).

A chave da solução foi primeiramente garantir que o container receba os eventos de teclado pois tags `div` normalmente não os recebem. Para isso adicionei o atributo `tabindex="-1"`. Depois foi só monitorar o evento `keydown` e mudar os extremos do eixo X a cada tecla de seta para a direita ou para a esquerda:

```
$('#container')
.on('keydown', function(event){
    var deltaX, hc, extr;
    if(event.which === 37 || event.which === 39) {
        deltaX = 1000000000; //ajuste esse tamanho a seu gosto
        if (event.which === 37) deltaX = -deltaX; // p/ esquerda
        hc = $('#container').highcharts();
        extr = hc.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
        hc.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extr.min + deltaX, extr.max + deltaX);
    }
})
```

Também coloquei o container em foco logo ao início, com `$('#container').focus();`.